# How can I add MX records for a Service Fabric Application

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, mx-record

We have a cname forwarding from a domain abc.xyz.com to a service fabric cluster in azure: abc.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.
Furthermore we have hosted an e-mail server in this cluster.

We could configure successfully a PTR record for the public IP of the cluster  by using the powershell commands "Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress"/"Set-AzureRmPublicIpAddress".

My question is now: How can I configure an MX record for the service fabric abc.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com?

I tried it with an Azure DNS zone but it seams not working.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: What did you do with the Azure DNS?

Comment: I added a zone for abc.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com in AZURE DNS, and added an mx record via the AZURE portal. But then i found out that we have to change the name servers in our domain registrar to the Azure DNS name servers. But this we dont want to do. Our solution is now to use a static IP for the cluster and configure an A record instead of a cname forwarding.

But is it possible to configure MX records for the service fabric cluster dns name, e.g.: abc.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com?